# How do I catch multiple Exceptions in a validation form

Tags: php, exception

I have a verification form for registering users and I am trying this concept of try-catching for validating input data in my model. Let me show you my code first:

Model Register

```
public function register (string $username, string $email, string $email_repeat, string $password, string $password_repeat, string $ip, string $reCaptcha) {
    $this->username = trim($username);
    $this->email = trim($email);
    $this->email_repeat = trim($email_repeat);
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->password_repeat = $password_repeat;
    $this->ip = $ip;
    $this->reCaptcha_response = $reCaptcha;
    $this->reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha(GOOGLE_CAPTCHA_SECRET); //the API secret is in the config.php file

    $this->verifyEmail();
    $this->verifyUsername();
    $this->verifyPassword();
    $this->validateReCaptcha($this->reCaptcha_response, $this->ip);

    $this->db->insertRow("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [$this->username, $this->password, $this->email]);
}

public function verifyEmail () {
    if(empty($this->email) || empty($this->email_repeat)) {
        throw new \Exception('Email address is empty');
    }

    $isTaken = $this->db->getRow("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM users WHERE email= ?", [$this->email]);
    if($isTaken->count > 0){
        throw new \Exception('This email is taken');
    }
}


private function verifyUsername () {
    if(strlen($this->username) < 3 || strlen($this->username) > 15) {
        throw new \Exception('Username must be between 3 and 15 symbols');
    }

    $isTaken = $this->db->getRow("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM users WHERE username= ?", [$this->username]);
    if($isTaken->count > 0){
        throw new \Exception('This username is taken');
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function register ()
{
    if($this->post != null) {
        try {
            $register = $this->tableRegister->register(
                $_POST['username'],
                $_POST['email'],
                $_POST['email_repeat'],
                $_POST['password'],
                $_POST['password_repeat'],
                $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']
            );
        } catch (\Exception $err) {
            $this->flashMessage->error($err->getMessage());
        }
    }
    $this->renderView('users/register');
}
```

As you can see in the model, both methods `validateEmail` and `validateUsername` go through the database and check if the email or username are taken. If both of them are taken, I want to catch both of the exceptions, as well as every other exception that might occur - if email is taken, if username is taken, if username is invalid.. everything. Currently my script ends at the first exception. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When an exception is thrown, code following the statement will not be
>   executed, and PHP will attempt to find the first matching catch block.
>   If an exception is not caught, a PHP Fatal Error will be issued with
>   an "Uncaught Exception ..." message, unless a handler has been defined
>   with set_exception_handler() ([source](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)).

A good solution here is to add the `errors` property, `hasErrors` and `getErrors` methods for the model. This will allow you to store and to handle error check for each form field.

For example:

```
public function verifyEmail () {
    if(empty($this->email) || empty($this->email_repeat)) {
        $this->errors['email'] = 'Email address is empty';
        return false;
    }

    $isTaken = $this->db->getRow("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM users WHERE email= ?",
       [$this->email]);
    if($isTaken->count > 0){
        $this->errors['email'] = 'This email is taken';
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public function hasErrors() {
    return !empty($this->errors);
}

public function getErrors() {
    return $this->errors;
}
```

Add check to the `register` method in the model:

```
if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
    $this->db->insertRow("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
     [$this->username, $this->password, $this->email]);
}
```

Then add check in your controller:

```
if ($this->tableRegister->hasErrors()) { 
    $this->flashMessage->error('The form has error(s): '
        .implode("; \r\n", $this->tableRegister->getErrors()));
} else {
    // code for user registration here
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I decided to have one error at the time but thank you for the detailed answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a try-catch in your Model `register` function, e.g.

```
public function register (string $username, string $email, string $email_repeat, string $password, string $password_repeat, string $ip, string $reCaptcha) {
    try{
        $this->username = trim($username);
        $this->email = trim($email);
        $this->email_repeat = trim($email_repeat);
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->password_repeat = $password_repeat;
        $this->ip = $ip;
        $this->reCaptcha_response = $reCaptcha;
        $this->reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha(GOOGLE_CAPTCHA_SECRET); //the API secret is in the config.php file

        $this->verifyEmail();
        $this->verifyUsername();
        $this->verifyPassword();
        $this->validateReCaptcha($this->reCaptcha_response, $this->ip);

        $this->db->insertRow("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [$this->username, $this->password, $this->email]);
    } catch(\Exception ex){
        //handle error
        throw new \Exception("Error registering user"); //this will pass the exception up to the calling method instead of just killing the page
    }
}
```

If either `verifyEmail` or `verifyUsername` throw errors, these stop the rest of the code from executing. As they're not handled correctly, this stops execution of the entire page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I see what you mean. But this would be ugly to have 5 different try-catch for 5 different methods.

Comment: I agree. However, in your scenario you will need to fail if either the Email or Username are incorrect, so you can just use one big try-catch (correct me if I'm wrong)? Just wrap the whole of that method in a try-catch